# When to take dummy variables in classification problems?

Tags: r, classification, random-forest, logistic-regression, dummy-variable

I am doing a binary classification problem where I am predicting if a customer will subscribe for a campaign(For Airline Industry).

My data set is at Customer and Campaign name level and there are 43 variables under consideration.

There are certain variables which are decile ( 1 to 10) and variable like education level ( 0 to 5). For education level we can't say 4 is twice as educated as 2. **How should I treat my variables?**

Do i need to convert these variables to *dummy variables( 0 or 1)*, I am running Logistic regression, random forest, Xgboost in R. 
How can I check variable importance if I convert these to dummy variables( factor analysis is throwing errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need dummy variables, in my opinion. How about converting `educational level` into multiple variables like these:

`educational level:1`

`educational level:2`

`educational level:3`

and so on. Then you can give dummy variables for each of the variable.

For example,

`educational level:1` yes:1 no:0

`educational level:2` yes:1 no:0

Then fit your data into logistic model and try to resample it with some kind of ways like "cross validation". But I'm not quite sure about `"variable importance"`, do you mean is this variable statistically significant or ...?